# Match word in a string that does not end in ellipsis

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

Let's say I have the following string:

`ZD:123123 ZD:213123 ZD:2e213 [ZD:213123] [ZD#221313] ZD:234...`

I want to pattern match every occurrence *except* `ZD:234...` because I don't want any words that have an elipses.

This pattern was doing nicely for me in JavaScript:

`/(\[|\(|)ZD[:#]\w+(\]|\)|)/g`

However, it still captures the `ZD:234` part of `ZD:234...` which I absolutely don't want it to do.

How can I prevent regex from doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy fix is to use a negative lookahead:

```
/(\[|\(|)ZD[:#]\w+\b(\]|\)|)(?!\.\.\.)/g
```

Note that I've also added `\b` to avoid matching on `ZD:23`.

A bit simplified:

```
/[\[(]?ZD[:#]\w+\b[\])]?(?!\.\.\.)/g
```

In case you want matching brackets (no `[ZD:123)`):

```
/(?:ZD[:#]\w+|\[ZD[:#]\w+\]|\(ZD[:#]\w+\))\b(?!\.\.\.)/g
```

Comment: +1 nice. Do you think `\.{3}` would be cleaner for the ellipsis though? Just throwing ideas out there... :)

Comment: Hmm, this seems to match `ZD:23` from `ZD:234...`, it's one character less so it's progress, but I don't want it to match any part of `ZD:234...` at all

Comment: \.\.\. vs \.{3} is all a stylistic choice. Which do you prefer? Which is easier for you to read and understand at a glance?  Which is easier for your coworkers/partners/anyone else who will review your code to understand?  I prefer \.\.\., but that's just me.

Comment: @Kobi - ah, excellent! That actually makes a lot of sense to me now, so thanks for that!

Comment: There's also the too clever `(?:\[(?=.*?(\]))|\((?=.*?(\)))|)ZD[:#]\w+\b\1\2(?!\.\.\.)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to skin a cat. The following will work in more browsers by using a simpler regular expression:

```
function trim(s) {
  return s.replace(/^ | $/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');
}

var x = 'ZD:123123 ZD:213123 ZD:2e213... [ZD:213123] [ZD#221313] ZD:234...';
alert(
  trim(x.replace(/(^| )[^ ]+[\.]{3}( |$)/g,' ')).split(/\s+/)
);

/* shows: ZD:123123,ZD:213123,[ZD:213123],[ZD#221313] */
```

It removes any space delimited "word" of characters ending in ... and then splits on the space.